# Two Questions on the paper Near-optimal Regret Bounds for Reinforcement Learning

Tags: markov-chains, reinforcement-learning

I am reading the classic paper Near-optimal Regret Bounds for Reinforcement Learning. I have two questions:

1. How to combine all MDPs in $ \mathcal{M} $ to get a single MDP with extended action space?
2. Why value iteration on the MDP $\tilde{M}^{+}$ with continuous action is equivalent to value iteration on an MDP with finite action set?

These two steps are important for understanding the algorithm UCRL2. But I cannot see why they are true based on the concise explanations in the paper. Any comment is much appreciated!